# How to send a message to a Discord Channel every X seconds?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net, system.timers.timer

I created a Discord Bot where I can send text commands. For example, typing !start, would send the message that has the start parameter set. The bot works, I can send the commands, I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to set the timer and tie it to the command. Maybe setting it up as a command is the wrong way to go about it, but I can't figure out another way to send a message.

Here is my code so far. I've looked in several places online. Many resources say I need to include the System.Timer using, which I have. I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to tie the timer, the command itself, and which channel it goes into, all together. Any help would be appreciated.

```cs
using Discord.Commands;
using System.Timers;

namespace MessageTimerBot.Modules
{

    public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("start")]
        public async Task StartMessageTimer()
        {

        }

        public class MessageTimer
        {

            private static System.Timers.Timer messageTimer;

            public static void StartTimer()
            {
                messageTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
                messageTimer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
                messageTimer.AutoReset = true;
                messageTimer.Enabled = true;
            }

            public static void OnTimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test Message");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using C# Timer Interval ?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding it correctly you just need to make your `OnTimerElapsed` method async:

`public static async void OnTimerElapsed(...)`

Then create a global variable `SocketCommandContext _Context;` in your MessageTimer Class, add the attribute `SocketCommandContext context` to the StartTime method and set `_Context` to `context`

And then Call
`await _Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Test Message");` in your `OnTimerElapsed` method:

```
public static Class MessageTimer
{
   private static System.Timers.Timer messageTimer;
   private static SocketCommandContext _Context;

   public static void StartTimer(SocketCommandContext context)
   {
      _Context = context;

      messageTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
      messageTimer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
      messageTimer.AutoReset = true;
      messageTimer.Enabled = true;
   }

   public static void OnTimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
      _Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Test Message");
      Console.WriteLine("Test Message");
   }
}
```

Now you just need to call `MessageTimer.StartTimer(Context);` in your start command

```
public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
   [Command("start")]
   public async Task StartMessageTimer()
   {
      MessageTimer.StartTimer(Context);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this example](https://gist.github.com/Joe4evr/967949a477ed0c6c841407f0f25fa730) to set up my automated message system. It still works on the latest version of Discord.NET (v 3.6.1 as of the date this post goes up)

```
using System;
using System.Threading; // 1) Add this namespace
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord.Commands;

public class TimerService
{
    private readonly Timer _timer; // 2) Add a field like this
    // This example only concerns a single timer.
    // If you would like to have multiple independant timers,
    // you could use a collection such as List<Timer>,
    // or even a Dictionary<string, Timer> to quickly get
    // a specific Timer instance by name.

    public TimerService(DiscordSocketClient client)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(async _ =>
        {
            // 3) Any code you want to periodically run goes here, for example:
            var chan = client.GetChannel(knownId) as IMessageChannel;
            if (chan != null)
                await chan.SendMessageAsync("hi");
        },
        null,
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),  // 4) Time that message should fire after the timer is created
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)); // 5) Time after which message should repeat (use `Timeout.Infinite` for no repeat)
    }

    public void Stop() // 6) Example to make the timer stop running
    {
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Restart() // 7) Example to restart the timer
    {
        _timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
    }
}

public class TimerModule : ModuleBase
{
    private readonly TimerService _service;

    public TimerModule(TimerService service) // Make sure to configure your DI with your TimerService instance
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    // Example commands
    [Command("stoptimer")]
    public async Task StopCmd()
    {
        _service.Stop();
        await ReplyAsync("Timer stopped.");
    }

    [Command("starttimer")]
    public async Task RestartCmd()
    {
        _service.Restart();
        await ReplyAsync("Timer (re)started.");
    }
}
```

You would need to set up Dependency Injection in your startup file for this to work correctly. If you don't know how to do that, the [Discord.NET](https://discordnet.dev/guides/text_commands/dependency-injection.html) and [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) should give you a good idea of what to do.